# How can I optimize a query that does an ORDER BY on a derived column in MySQL?

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I am having trouble optimizing a relatively simple query involving a GROUP BY, ORDER BY, and LIMIT.  The table has just over 300,000 records.  Here's the schema (I added some extra indexes to experiment with):

```
CREATE TABLE `scrape_search_results` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `creative_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `access_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `creative_url_index` (`creative_id`,`url_id`),
  KEY `access_date_index` (`access_date`),
  KEY `access_date_creative_id_index` (`access_date`,`creative_id`),
  KEY `creative_id_access_date_index` (`creative_id`,`access_date`),
  KEY `test_index` USING HASH (`creative_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4252725 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In the table, a single `creative_id` may appear multiple (hundreds) of times.  The query I am trying to answer is a relatively simple one; give me the first 20 `creative_ids` ordered by `access_date`.  Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT `ScrapeSearchResult`.`creative_id`, 
        MAX(`ScrapeSearchResult`.`access_date`) AS `latest_access_date` 
FROM `scrape_search_results` AS `ScrapeSearchResult` 
WHERE 1 = 1 
GROUP BY `ScrapeSearchResult`.`creative_id` 
ORDER BY `latest_access_date` DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

Here's the results of executing this query, where we see the 20th largest `access_date` is 2010-08-23 11:03:25:

```
+-------------+---------------------+
| creative_id | latest_access_date  |
+-------------+---------------------+
|         550 | 2010-08-23 11:07:49 | 
|        4568 | 2010-08-23 11:07:49 | 
|         552 | 2010-08-23 11:07:49 | 
|        2109 | 2010-08-23 11:07:49 | 
|        5221 | 2010-08-23 11:07:49 | 
|        1544 | 2010-08-23 11:07:49 | 
|        1697 | 2010-08-23 11:07:49 | 
|         554 | 2010-08-23 11:07:12 | 
|         932 | 2010-08-23 11:05:48 | 
|       11029 | 2010-08-23 11:05:37 | 
|       11854 | 2010-08-23 11:05:27 | 
|       11856 | 2010-08-23 11:05:05 | 
|         702 | 2010-08-23 11:03:56 | 
|        4319 | 2010-08-23 11:03:56 | 
|        7159 | 2010-08-23 11:03:56 | 
|       10610 | 2010-08-23 11:03:46 | 
|        5540 | 2010-08-23 11:03:46 | 
|           1 | 2010-08-23 11:03:46 | 
|       11942 | 2010-08-23 11:03:35 | 
|        7900 | 2010-08-23 11:03:25 | 
+-------------+---------------------+
```

If I was going to write this algorithm by hand, I would build a b-tree ordered on (`access_date`, `creative_id`).  I'd start at the `MAX(access_date)` and keep walking the tree until I found 20 unique `creative_ids`, which I would then return in the order I found them in.

Using that algorithm, I would need to consider just 94 rows (there are 94 rows for which `access_date >= 2010-08-23 11:03:25`, which is our 20th largest `access_date` as shown above).

However, MySQL decides to use `creative_url_index` when answering this query, which I don't understand.  It considers over 10,000 rows when doing this.

```
ANALYZE TABLE scrape_search_results;
SELECT ...;
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+--------------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key                | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+--------------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ScrapeSearchResult | index | NULL          | creative_url_index | 8       | NULL | 10687 | Using temporary; Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+--------------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Is my trouble that I am performing an ORDER BY on the derived-column `MAX(access_date)`?  If so, how can I optimize my query to perform more in-line with my expectations?

Comment: Run: `ANALYZE TABLE scrape_search_results`, and re-run your tests.  The optimizer uses it's algorithm based on table statistics, which change over time

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thanks for the tip, but I did run that exact query right before my SELECT.  The results I showed are the outcome post-analyze.  And for reference, there are 10812 distinct creative_ids in the table, which is close to (but not exactly) the number of records the query plan considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done this sort of thing in MySQL for a while (long since switched to PostgtreSQL) but typically I would handle this with concentric selects to trick the query planner into giving a good plan.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT `ScrapeSearchResult`.`creative_id`, 
        MAX(`ScrapeSearchResult`.`access_date`) AS `latest_access_date` 
FROM `scrape_search_results` AS `ScrapeSearchResult` 
WHERE 1 = 1 
GROUP BY `ScrapeSearchResult`.`creative_id` 

) as inner
ORDER BY `latest_access_date` DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

The success of this will purely depend on a reasonable number of total rows in the inner though.

I just looked up the docs for MySQL 5.6 and it *looks* like this *should* work ... even in MySQL ;)

Comment: @Trey: Excellent, your suggestion brought the time down from 0.44 sec to 0.17 sec.  The new query plan built a temporary table and then queried it.  The `creative_id_access_date_index` column was used (again, searching 10687 rows but not using temporary or filesort, and instead using-index-for-group-by), which I believe accounts for the speedup.  Any other suggestions to bring the number of rows considered down at all, for an even greater boost in speed?

Comment: Didn't want to mess up the comment above; here's the new EXPLAIN output:
\n
1 PRIMARY <derived2>         ALL   NULL NULL                          NULL NULL 10812 Using filesort
\n
2 DERIVED ScrapeSearchResult range NULL creative_id_access_date_index 4    NULL 10687 Using index for group-by

Comment: As long as you have no WHERE condition it's going to do a full table scan.  If you could put any sort of condition on the query at all it will help considerably.    My query will only help speed up the sort ... not so much reduce the number of rows scanned.

Comment: I don't know how often you are adding / pruning data but you might want to make a summary table and select from there (where you only have the results of the inner query).   You can maintain with code or with insert / update triggers.  That will cause all sorting to be done with an appropriate index (if you add one).

Comment: In mysql, group by also does an "order by" on the same columns. Perhaps you would want to eliminate that, then modify it this way: `GROUP BY ScrapeSearchResult.creative_id  order by null ) as inner `

Comment: @ceteras: Interesting, didn't know this about MySQL at all.  It made about 0.9 s difference when I explicitly ordered by NULL.  Thanks!